# Implementing ranged-loop in custom hashed set: accessing only entries not marked as empty

Tags: c++, iteration, containers, hashset, ranged-loops

## Container basic setup

I have implemented a simple custom unordered set container, that uses hashing. Internally, it stores data like this:

```
class Set
{
    T *data = nullptr;
    bool *emptyList = nullptr;
    int size = 0;

    ... (inner methos go here)
};
```

That is, it stores two arrays. One called `data` with the actual values of templated type `T`, and another called `emptyList` with `bool` values that mark whether at that position the set is considered empty or not.

This way, linearly probing to store new values and also erasing entries become way cheaper. Both become, respectively, just a matter of finding the next the `emptyList[index] = true`, or of setting it to `true`.

## Problem with the ranged for-loop

Currently, I allow iteration over the values stored in the set like `for(auto i : set_instance)` by having the following public member functions in the set class:

```
T* begin() const { data[0] };
T* end() const { data[end] };
```

The problem with that, of course, is that a ranged for-loop also accesses the entries in `data` that should not be accessed since they are marked in `emptyList` as being empty.

Is there a way for me to make it so that when the user tries to iterate over the set with ranged loops, only the entries in `data` that correspond to the entries in `emptyList` that are **not** marked as `true` are actually accessed/processed by the ranged loop?

Comment: Just write your iterator to only access the elements that you're interested in.

Comment: @PeteBecker Could you elaborate a little bit on how to do that, or point me to a link that discusses a similar case? After searching, almost all examples or discussion I find is on the standard access via iterator

Comment: I'm curious why there is a `bool *` in there. Doesn't a simple bool take up the same space? What would the pointer reference (some global boolean? Or a unique value for each object? Why not just have a `getState` method to do the same?)? Sorry for the multiple questions, I'm just really interested.

Comment: I guess why I'm curious is the `bool *` will return true so long as it isn't pointed at `nullptr` but if it is dereferenced and set to `true` or `false`, it will always return `true` regardless of what is stored at that address.

Comment: @Juddy -- one way would be for your interator to be defined by a class that holds a pointer to your container and an index. `operator*` would return the object at the index. `operator++` would increment the index as many times as needed to get to the next valid object.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks! Ok, just one question. I was able to implement almost all of it for the array `_emptyList` (since that is the array where iterations have to be checked).  The only bit I am in doubt is how to implement `operator*`. What is the correct way to use a pointer to that `bool` array to get the corresponding entry in the `T`array? Should I implement the iterator as a nested class of the Set? Right now I pass a pointer to `data` when an iterator is instantiated, then I calculate index by calculating `itr - begin()`. But this looks dirty. Would it be better to have the iterator

Comment: @NonCreature0714 I don't quite get your doubt. The `bool*` is just a `bool` array.

Comment: @Juddy "doubt" is a stronger word than I feel. I looked at your code and was a little confused, I suppose, because the question is about ranged for-loops, but I didn't see implementation of those in the snippet. I'm also not sure why using a bool array is "cheaper" than simply setting a data object to null, and only accessing the value of an item is !null. Iterating past null values should happen very quickly, without the need of a parallel array. Again "doubt" is a strong word, but certainly I'm curious, because I found your problem interesting else I wouldn't have asked questions.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 Oh, no problem at all about the questions. I appreciate your interest. If you want to turn to the chat, I would gladly explain in more detail what I am doing.